# how to use image on menu text

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me here, i like to use image on background of Menu TextOn and Hover.
 image size Width: 108 px heigh: 37 px

CSS:

```
a.menuTextOff:link {
color:#333c50;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a.menuTextOff:visited {
color:#333c50;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.menuTextOff:hover {
color:#000000;
text-shadow:1px 1px #e4dcd0;
text-decoration: underline;
}
a.menuTextOn:link {
color:#000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.menuTextOn:visited {
color:#000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.menuTextOn:hover {
text-shadow:1px 1px #e4dcd0;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!--MENU VIEW-->
<?$theClass="menuTextOff";?><?if($_GET['c']=="home" || $_GET['c']==""){$theClass="menuTextOn";}?><div style="position:absolute; top:104px; left:51px;"><a class="<?=$theClass?>" href="app.php">HOME</a></div>
        <?$theClass="menuTextOff";?><?if($_GET['c']=="games"){$theClass="menuTextOn";}?>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:104px; left:175px;"><a class="<?=$theClass?>" href="app.php?c=games">MY GAMES</a></div>
        <?$theClass="menuTextOff";?><?if($_GET['c']=="scoreboard"){$theClass="menuTextOn";}?><div style="position:absolute; top:104px; left:330px;"><a class="<?=$theClass?>" href="app.php?c=scoreboard">SCOREBOARD</a></div>
        <?$theClass="menuTextOff";?><?if($_GET['c']=="forums"){$theClass="menuTextOn";}?><div style="position:absolute; top:104px; left:610px;"><a class="<?=$theClass?>" href="app.php?c=forums">FORUMS</a></div>
        <?$theClass="menuTextOff";?><?if($_GET['c']=="information"){$theClass="menuTextOn";}?><div style="position:absolute; top:104px; left:780px;"><a class="<?=$theClass?>" href="app.php?c=information">INFORMATION</a></div>
        <?$theClass="menuTextOff";?><?if($_GET['c']=="blog"){$theClass="menuTextOn";}?><div style="position:absolute; top:104px; left:950px;"><a class="<?=$theClass?>" href="app.php?c=blog">BLOG</a></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can create a minimal example of your problem with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It is difficult to help when there is no concrete example to work with.

Comment: and tell us what's not working specifically